# UIWindow rotation bug in iOS8 for custom alert

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I've updated my custom alert class (which is a `UIWindow` subclass) in iOS8 to set its `rootViewController` to the `UIViewController` it is being presented on. This enables the app to automatically rotate my custom alert instead of having to do it manually.

It works well but I'm finding one situation where it doesn't rotate: when I'm on the `UIViewController` that appears when the app is first launched (which also happens to be the `rootViewController` of my app delegates `window` property).

Is this because `UIViewController` can't be the `rootViewController` of two `UIWindows` or is it a bug? Does anyone have a work around for this? It works perfectly on every other `UIViewController` that I display an alert.

Comment: Why did you make it a `UIWindow` subclass and not a `UiViewController` that you add as a child controller to the rootViewController of the app?

Comment: @pteofil In my app delegate, the UIWindow rootViewController is a UIViewController. I use UIWindow for my custom alerts so I can place the window above the status bar.

Comment: You can take a [snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:) of your active view controller, and add the snapshot view as the background of your alert window, to avoid reassigning the view controller as the root of another window.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite The problem is that the view attached to my subclassed UIWindow isn't rotating. I don't understand how your suggestion would fix that unless I'm not understanding what you mean?